# Relation between $l^{2}(\mathbb{Z}^{d})$ and $s'$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

Let:
$$l^{2}(\mathbb{Z}^{d}) := \{\psi:\mathbb{Z}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}: \hspace{0.1cm} \sum_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^{d}}|\psi(x)|^{2} < \infty\}.$$
and, for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, define:
$$s_{m} := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}: \hspace{0.1cm} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2m}|x_{n}|^{2}\equiv ||x||_{m}^{2} < \infty\}$$
Is there any relation between $l^{2}(\mathbb{Z}^{d})$ and $s':=\bigcup_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}s_{m}$? I think the inclusion $l^{2}(\mathbb{Z}^{d}) \subset s'$ probably holds but I don't know for sure. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Elements of $\ell_2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ are functions $\mathbb{Z}^d\to\mathbb{K}$, the elements of $s_m$ are functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{K}$. Formally, you cannot have $s_m\subseteq\ell_2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ nor $\ell_2(\mathbb{Z}^d)\subseteq s'$.

On the other hand, for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ one can define $w_m\in\mathbb{K}^{\mathbb{N}}$ by
$w_m = (n^m)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and,  denoting by $\mu$ the counting measure in $\mathbb{N}$, one has that $s_m$ is just the weighted Hilbert space $\ell_2(\mathbb{N}, w_m\mu)$. It is straightforward to check that $s_m\subseteq s_{m'}$ whenever $m\geq m'$. What may not be so trivial is that these inclusions are bounded linear operators. It seems (and I don't know if it is true) that we can equip $s'$ with the canonical direct limit Hilbert space structure $\varinjlim s_m$.
Probably $s'$ and $\ell_2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ are isomorphic as separable Hilbert spaces, but this isomorphism is not canonical.